# Why does the object (containing an array) passed to second function, give an empty array when I try to access its array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am getting a response ***data***. I pass it to another function and then log it. The first time I log the entire object and get the desired output, but the second time I try to log the array inside that object, I get an empty array. (I have cross checked that array is not empty).

```
const f1 = () => {
  window.gapi.load('analytics', async function() {
    window.gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      'serverAuth': {
        'access_token': access_token
      }
    });
    const data = await new window.gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector-container'

    });
    data.execute();
    f2(data);
  });

}

const f2 = async function (data){
  console.log(data);
  console.log(data["zt"]["iH"]);
}
```

response1:

```
      {…}
​
Jd: Object { Lb: false, Zh: 1, Sw: 0, … }
​
Rb: Object { container: "view-selector-container" }
​
TM: Object { Lb: false, gx: false, Va: true, … }
​
hH: Object { Lb: false, gx: false, Va: true, … }
​
ids: "ga:176819049"
​
mP: Object { Lb: false, gx: false, Va: true, … }
​
zt: Object { iH: (9) […], gH: {…}, SM: {…}, … }
```

response2:

```
  []
​
length: 0
​
<prototype>: Array []
```

data from console.log(data["zt"])

```
​
zt: {
​​
SM: Object { "UA-xx2": {…}, "UA-xx-1": {…}, "UA-xx-1": {…}, … }
​​
gH: Object { 34199158: {…}, 44335927: {…}, 64056475: {…}, … }
​​
iH: Array(9) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​
r3: Object { 63179797: {…}, 77047380: {…}, 91559901: {…}, … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { fetch: fetch(), … }
​
<prototype>: Object { constructor: RE(a), execute: execute(), gt: gt(), … }
    }
```

as can be seen from the response above, ***iH*** is an array of length 9, but when I log it I get an empty array

Comment: Update the JSON of data please.

Comment: Can you please post the result of `console.log(data)`? It would help a lot

Comment: You claim *but the second time I try to log it with a desired key*, yet the engine isn't going to betray and says it doesnt exist when it does. Don't blame the engine. Blame your code. Show the "console.log" as @JeremyAnderson mentions and then you can get some help from SO. .... Meaning, update your question with the results of `console.log(data);`.

Comment: just updated with responses.

Comment: Please add the data from `console.log(data['zt'])`. This is hidden.

Comment: Your "response2:" says it is an empty array: `Array []` not `undefined` as indicated in your question. I'm not sure you have a problem, you have an empty array.

Comment: just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an async problem, where the data object only gets filled after you console.log it. Try logging `console.log({...data})` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` to make sure the data is there when f2 is called.

Background: When you console.log(data), and then look at it in the console, then it will contain changes that occur even after the console.log call. This is because data is an object, and you are just logging the reference to the object, not the value of the object itself. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/f61tdue5/3/

Comment: This is what is happening, if I check output of console.log(data) immediately after refresh it remains an empty object, but when I check it after say 10 seconds it contains values. But I consistently get empty array if I log a key of the data object.

Comment: on running console.log({...data}) I get an empty object

Comment: In that case, it's clear that data.execute is async, and you are not waiting for the result. You might have to bind the execution of f2 to an event listener, like `data.on('change', function(updated) {
  console.log(updated); f2(updated);
});` or something.

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere in the google analytics api documentation that execute() is an async function, your suggestion saved my night

Comment: Happy to hear! I saw that they mention the data.on part in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

try this way
`console.log(data[zt]) console.log(data[iH])`

or

`console.log(data[zt],data[iH])`